# What is healthy load % for CPU?

Tags: processor

I would like to do some computation on my PC.
Thereby I wonder - what is healthy load for CPU?  I mean at which maximum CPU load % my CPU would survive the longest.
Or should I watch for other parameters, like temperature?

Answer (score 1):

For your microprocessor you should worry only about voltage and temperature; in that order. Everything else is mostly irrelevant.